# event.pageX won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've experienced this problem once. I don't know why **event.pageX** doesn't work. It returns an error that says "script error." Please help me fix my problem.

JS (snippet)

```
function warning() {
    function show() {
        alert('No cheating!')
    }
    if (event.pageX > 456) {
        setInterval(show, 50)
    }
}
```

I uploaded jQuery 3.1.1 properly and it's not because I defined a function inside a function. I did that in another code and it worked fine. Also I know it's not the defined function inside the function because when I remove the conditional it does not say "Script error."

Comment: `function warning(event)`

Comment: *'It returns an error that says "script error."'* - That's a very vague error message. Are you sure the browser's console doesn't tell you anything else about the error? Anyway, why are you trying to pop up an alert every 50ms?

Comment: Show full code context...we don't even know where you call this from. See [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

`event` is not a global variable. It does work on old versions of IE, but for newer browsers, the event needs to be declared as an argument on your event handler.

```js
function warning(event) {
  console.log(event.pageX);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', warning);
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```